# Theorem environment generates missing `\begin{document}` eror

Tags: errors, compiling, amsthm

Consider

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{boldtheorem}
{}
{}
{\itshape}
{}
{}
{\itshape}
{}
{\bfseries}
{.}
{ }
{\thmnumber{#2}\ifx #3\relax\relax\thmname{ #1}\else\thmnote{ #3}\fi}
\theoremstyle{boldtheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this with `latex` gives a Missing `\begin{document}` error on the line `{.}`.

Removing the `.` gives the error

```
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode.
<argument> ##
         2
l.14 {\thmnumber{#2}
                \ifx #3\relax\relax\thmname{ #1}\else\thmnote{ #3}\fi}
```

This is extracted from a larger preamble. I have removed all non-printable characters using the vim command `:%s/[^[:print]]//g`, but the error persists. Removing the `.aux` file does not seem to have an effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: The `\newtheoremstyle` macro takes exactly 9 parameters.  The line `{.}` is a tenth parameter...

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks. I think I accidentally inserted another pair of curly brackets in between `\itshape` and `\bfseries`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `thmtest.tex` (edited)

```
\newtheoremstyle{<name>}% name
  {<dimen>}%              Space above
  {<dimen>}%              Space below
  {<font>}%               Body font
  {}%                     Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {<font>}%               Thm head font
  {<punct>}%              Punctuation after thm head
  {<dimen>}%              Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space; \newline = linebreak
  {<spec>}%               Thm head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')
```

If you count the number of arguments, they're exactly nine.

So you probably want

```
\newtheoremstyle{boldtheorem}
  {\topsep}
  {\topsep}
  {\itshape}
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {.}
  { }
  {\thmnumber{#2}\ifx\relax#3\relax\thmname{ #1}\else\thmnote{ #3}\fi}
```

Note that `#3` has to be *between* the two `\relax` tokens, if you want to test for its emptyness.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newtheoremstyle{boldtheorem}
  {\topsep}
  {\topsep}
  {\itshape}
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {.}
  { }
  {\thmnumber{#2}\ifx\relax#3\relax\thmname{ #1}\else\thmnote{ #3}\fi}

\theoremstyle{boldtheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{Title}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{theorem}[Fancy theorem]
This is a fancy theorem.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: uh, you've defined `boldtheorem`, but this example doesn't test it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Look more closely. `;-)`

Comment: sorry.  stupid inattention.  (tired out from shoveling snow.)

Comment: It is perhaps worth mentioning that the `amsthm` package has an `\@ifempty` test that can be used instead of `\ifx\relax#3\relax`.