# "Loose" section/paragraph numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering, sections-paragraphs

**EDIT**
Playing around with the nice `amsthm` solution by egreg below I realized that I really would prefer an equivalent `ntheorem` construction. Can anyone help out here?

---

There are Math books which use a "loose" section/paragraph numbering style like this:

> **Chapter 1 Foundations**
>
> **(1.1) Definition**
>
> [...]
>
> **(1.2) Remark**
>
> [...]
>
> **(1.3)**
>
> [Some more content without an explicit title, possibly spanning several paragraphs.]
>
> **(1.4) Theorem**
>
> [...]
>
> **Proof** [...]
>
> **(1.5)**
>
> [Some other background story without explicit title, possibly spanning several paragraphs.]
>
> **(1.6) Some free title like "Further insight"**
>
> [...]

I hope you get the idea. What is the recommended way to achieve such a numbering style in Latex? Is it possible within the `amsthm` or `ntheorem` Package?

**Addition**

The style I observed in some books is that the numbering is always given in parentheses (maybe to distinguish them from normal chapter/sectioning numbering). Number and (if given) title are in bold font, but same font size as normal text.

Comment: Is there an associated ToC? If so, what do you put for the empty numbered paragraphs? Also, did you mean to place brackets around the numbering?

Comment: @Werner No ToC is needed, but \ref{...} should work. I've added some info on parentheses and font to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not so difficult with `amsthm`: it just takes to define some suitable theorem styles. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17555/4427 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353540/4427

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{azimutplain}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {}          % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {(\thmnumber{#2}) \thmname{#1}\@ifnotempty{#3}{ (\thmnote{#3})}.} % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\newtheoremstyle{azimutdefinition}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\normalfont}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {}          % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {(\thmnumber{#2}) \thmname{#1}\@ifnotempty{#3}{ (\thmnote{#3})}.} % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\newtheoremstyle{azimutloose}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\normalfont}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {}          % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {(\thmnumber{#2})\@ifnotempty{#3}{ \thmnote{#3}.}} % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{azimutplain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

\theoremstyle{azimutdefinition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\theoremstyle{azimutloose}
\newtheorem{looseinner}[theorem]{}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{loose}[1][]
 {\@ifempty{#1}{\looseinner}{\looseinner[#1]}}
 {\endlooseinner}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Foundations}

\begin{definition}
Some text
\end{definition}

\begin{remark}
Some text
\end{remark}

\begin{loose}
Some more content without an explicit title, possibly spanning several paragraphs.

Some more content without an explicit title, possibly spanning several paragraphs.
\end{loose}

\begin{theorem}
Some text
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Some text
\begin{loose}
Some other background story without explicit title, possibly spanning several paragraphs.

Some other background story without explicit title, possibly spanning several paragraphs.\qedhere
\end{loose}
\end{proof}

\begin{loose}[Further insight]
Some text
\end{loose}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This looks nice indeed. As I'm currently an `ntheorem`-user, is there a solution for `ntheorem`, too?

Comment: @azimut Sorry, I never consider `ntheorem`.

Answer (score 3):

[egreg's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/514014/48973) can easily be modified to use `ntheorem` instead of `amsthm`:

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{ntheorem}

\makeatletter
  \newtheoremstyle{azimut}%
    {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
            (##2)\ ##1\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%
    {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
            (##2)\ ##1:\ ##3\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}
  \newtheoremstyle{azimutnoname}%
    {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
            (##2)\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%
    {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
            (##2)\ ##3\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}
  \newtheoremstyle{azimutnonumber}%
    {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
            ##1\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%
    {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
            ##1:\ ##3\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{azimut}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\theoremstyle{azimutnoname}
\newtheorem{looseinner}[theorem]{}
\makeatletter
  \newenvironment{loose}[1][]
    {\ifx\relax#1\relax\looseinner\else\looseinner[#1]\fi}
    {\endlooseinner}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{azimutnonumber}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Foundations}

\begin{definition}
Some text
\end{definition}

\begin{remark}
Some text
\end{remark}

\begin{loose}
Some more content without an explicit title, possibly spanning several paragraphs.

Some more content without an explicit title, possibly spanning several paragraphs.
\end{loose}

\begin{theorem}
Some text
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Some text
\begin{loose}
Some other background story without explicit title, possibly spanning several paragraphs.

Some other background story without explicit title, possibly spanning several paragraphs.
\end{loose}
\end{proof}

\begin{loose}[Further insight]
Some text
\end{loose}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

---

The style definitions above are just an adapted version of `ntheorem`'s default style `break`. If you want to omit the line break after headings, use adapted versions of the `plain` style instead.

```latex
\makeatletter
  \newtheoremstyle{azimut}%
    {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont (##2)\ ##1\theorem@separator]}%
    {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont (##2)\ ##1:\ ##3\theorem@separator]}
  \newtheoremstyle{azimutnoname}%
    {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont (##2)\theorem@separator]}%
    {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont (##2)\ ##3\theorem@separator]}
  \newtheoremstyle{azimutnonumber}%
    {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\theorem@separator]}%
    {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1:\ ##3\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Many thanks! One more question: Is there a way to get rid of the newline at (1.3) and (1.5), such that the text starts right of the numbering, as in the answer of egreg?

Comment: @azimut I added the required definitions to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I gave the bounty to you now. I decided to accept the other answer, as it was the first working answer to the original question.